# How can I to change switch construction on conditional operator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

This is similiar code construction in both cases of switch except word sendPhoto/sendVideo. How I can to change it, simplify.

```
class Telegram {
    defineMedia = 'photo';
    static sendPost(ctx) {
        switch (this.defineMedia){
            case 'photo':
                this.getUrl((urlCallback) => {
                    ctx.telegram.sendPhoto/*sendPhoto*/(this.#chatId,
                        {url: urlCallback});
                });
                break;
            case 'video':
                this.getUrl((urlCallback) => {
                    ctx.telegram.sendVideo/*sendVideo*/(this.#chatId,
                        {url: urlCallback});
                });
                break;
        }
    }
}

Telegram.sendPost();
```

How can I to change a **switch** to something like this:

```
    this.getUrl((urlCallback) => {
        ctx.telegram.(this.defineMedia = 'photo' ? sendPhoto : sendVideo )(this.#chatId,
            {url: urlCallback});
    });
```

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+call+method+name+from+variable) of [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359788/4642212).

Comment: The class can be shortened to ``class Telegram { defineMedia = "photo"; static sendPost(ctx){ this.getUrl((urlCallback) => { ctx.telegram[`send${this.defineMedia.toUpperCase().slice(0, 1)}${this.defineMedia.slice(1)}`](this.#chatId, { url: urlCallback }); }); } }``.